# Android. Debuggable приложение тормозит

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка, сборка

Условия:

Я работаю на двух компьютерах - дома и на работе.
Я собираю одно и то же приложение с опцией `debuggable=true`.
Делаю я это на одном и том же девайсе.

Проблема:

При сборке на работе приложение не тормозит ни в `debug buildType` (будучи `debuggable`), ни в `release buildType`.
Но стоит мне собрать его дома, как в `debug buildType` приложение начинает тормозить на экранах с тяжелой версткой (множество `<include>'ов`). А если еще и в `debug`-режим войти, то просто кромешный ад! При этом в `release buildType` все летает на тех же самых экранах.

Вопрос:
Должны ли быть включены/выключены какие-то особые настройки `Android Studio`, чтобы оптимизировать работу `debuggable` приложения? (вроде и на работе и дома ставил студию одинаково, не изменяя каких-либо важных настроек). Быть может от самого компьютера зависит скорость работы приложения на телефоне (звучит фантастически, но я уже не знаю на что думать)

Comment: Попробуйте Instant Run  студии отключить

Comment: Черт возьми, это сработало! Не хотите оставить ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобное поведение может быть вызвано функцией `Instant Run` - она обновляет приложение в реальном времени при изменениях в коде в дебаг режиме. Это, надо полагать, требует постоянного обмена данными и их обработки, что нагружает и комп и девайс. Отключение оной может помочь.

Comment: Действительно, помогло!